# UITapGestureRecognizer seems not blocked by its subviews, is that normal?

Tags: ios, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I am new to iOS development here, and I am now trying to build a login page. 
The login page is a UICollectionViewCell in a whole screen CollectionView. The red area represents a UIImageView.

I want to achieve that when the keyboard is showing up and I tap the other area, instead of the keyboard, of the screen, the keyboard would dismiss. 
My current solution is applying a UITapGestureRecognizer on the self.view, and it works fine. However, whenever I tap the imageView, it would trigger that dismiss keyboard GestureRecognizer.

I want to ask is that a normal behavior of the gesture recognizer? Because the image view is a subview of the self.view, and I think the image view would block the self.view, which means blocking the UITapGestureRecgnizer on the self.view.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the subView is not blocking is because it is not consuming the touch event.

If a view receives a touch event but doesn’t consume it the that event gets passed up the view hierarchy all the way back to the OS lying behind your app.

If you don’t want your tap gesture recogniser to receive touches inside your image view then you can just turn on `isUserInteractionEnabled` on the image view.

This will then make the image view consume the touch event and the gesture recogniser won’t receive it.